# Red Black tree print in level order in C

Tags: c, red-black-tree

I have completed a red black tree in c and i find it hard to print it in level-order. I have a print-inorder but i cant imagine how am i supposed to display it as a tree in the console print. Is it feasible? Can we implement BFS or DFS here? i've found an algorithm in wiki but i cant apply it.
If anyone has code for it in C could you post it here so i can study it?
 from wiki:

```
levelorder(root) 
  q = empty queue
  q.enqueue(root)
  while not q.empty do
    node := q.dequeue()
    visit(node)
    if node.left ≠ null
      q.enqueue(node.left)
    if node.right ≠ null
      q.enqueue(node.right)
```

Comment: Is this homework? Please tag if it is.

Comment: well red black tree was for homework. printing it in that form is not. Its just for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a BFS, but it might be easier to do an [iterative deepening search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search), since that will save you the trouble of implementing a FIFO queue in C. Pseudocode:

```
algorithm iterative-deepening(root)
    D = max-depth(root)
    for d=0 to D
        depth-limited-search(root, d)

/* variant of DFS */
algorithm depth-limited-search(node, d)
    if node != NULL
        if d == 0
            print node.contents
        else
            depth-limited-search(node.left, d - 1)
            depth-limited-search(node.right, d - 1)
```

Comment: well how can i find the max depth of the RBT? do i have to add a counter somehow when i insert data?

Comment: @GeoPapas: there are lots of options to get the depth. Note that the properties of a red-black tree guarantee a certain maximum depth as a function of the number of elements. You can also do a DFS.

Comment: so i could make a single tree travel from root to a leaf(with left and right child equal to null) and count the nodes i have met. That should give an approximate height right?

Comment: @GeoPapas: and then do the appropriate arithmetic, since you want an upper bound on the depth, not a lower bound (or you won't be printing the entire tree). But yes, that would work.